# После установки докера перестал работать Genymotion

Tags: docker, genymotion

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После установки Doker desktop перестали запускаться андроиды в genimotion. Установил последнюю версию, проблема осталась. Поддержка виртуализации Hyper-V в компонентах windows у меня отключена. Подскажите что можно сделать

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LU1UbSt0WsE Нашел это видео. Помогло изменить настройки звука в virtualBox